# CD4052 multiplexer with different input voltages

Tags: voltage, pcb-design, current-measurement, multiplexer, esp32

I've been working on designing a PCB for my indoor garden and i'm facing a problem i dont understand.

In my design i use a multiplexer (cd4052), to choose which sense resistor my current sensing chip (ina219) is reading.
I have 4 different sense resistors,

- 12V in
- 5V (right after a linear regulator)
- 12V out LEDS 1
- 12V out LEDS 2

After receiving and soldering everything correctly (i guess), i end up measuring 11.3V where it should be 5V.

So i've soldered a 2nd PCB with only some components, the 5V output is correct until i solder the CD4052...

[image: multiplexer]

- MP_0, MP_1 and MP_2 are linked to a resistor on the 12V routes
- MP_3 is linked to a resistor on the 5V route

I may have missunderstood things about the CD4052 [documentation](https://www.ti.com/product/CD4052B) but i'm stuck anyway.

Thanks for reading/helping !

Comment: VDD must be at least your highest input voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying 12V to pins of a chip that is powered by 5V. It cannot handle that and current will flow via IO pin protection diodes from IO pins to 5V supply, which explains why the 5V is now 11.3V which is 12V minus one diode drop. The inputs and outputs of the chip must be within the range of the power supplies.

Answer (score 0):

The Absolute Maximum Ratings say:

> DC Input Voltage: –0.5 V … V<sub>DD</sub> + 0.5 V

(The reason for that are ESD protection diodes that try to clamp the voltages at the I/O pins to the supply rails.)

To be able to pass 12 V signals, the multiplexer must also use a 12 V supply. This implies that the control signals must be higher than 5 V, which requires a level shifter. Alternatively, change the entire circuit to use low-side sensing.